# What does the color of player names mean in Monster Hunter World?

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

I just saw this image and was wondering what the meaning of the different name colors is as well as how to unlock change the color.

[image]

So the question in total is, what is the meaning of each color and how do I unlock/change the color? Can the color be changed at will?

EDIT:

As it seems that the completion of specific quests changes to name color, I would like to know which quests specifically unlock which color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunterWorld/comments/d2173k/player_name_color_meanings/) (and partially [the official manual](https://game.capcom.com/manual/MHW/en/ps4/page/17/8)):

> Green is after story. Orange is for completing HR100, Blue is for entering MR, Purple is for clearing MR story.

> MR200 is yellow

It's an indication of progress through quests (not through ranks like the reddit post suggests!). Each of the quests to unlock the colours are optional, and are unlocked once you have passed that point in the game. For example, the MR200 quest:

> Apparently you need to do all the optionals that upgrade equipment like the mr 150 and mr 175 quests to upgrade mantles, to unlock it.

I've searched various forums in an attempt to find the relevant quests for each rank, and will link the source for each one in format: `[Color](source) - Description`

[Green](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/211368-monster-hunter-world/76341393) - Beat the final story quest, [Land of Convergence](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Land+of+Convergence)

[Orange](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/211368-monster-hunter-world/76341393) - Beat [The Sapphire Star's Guidance](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/The+Sapphire+Star%27s+Guidance)

[Blue](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunterWorld/comments/d2173k/player_name_color_meanings/ezs5src?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) - Buy the Iceborne DLC

[Purple](https://gamewith.net/monsterhunterworld-iceborne/article/show/10920) - Beat the final story quest of the DLC, [Paean of Guidance](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Paean+of+Guidance)

[Gold/Yellow](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunterWorld/comments/d2173k/player_name_color_meanings/fbw69mv?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) - Beat [Master Hunter of the New World](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Master+Hunter+of+the+New+World), unlocked by completing all the MR optionals

There is no indication that you can change this colour anywhere on the internet, though if you get two, please try, and tell me.